# Python Cassandra driver not installed, or not on PYTHONPATH on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, cassandra, cqlsh

I am trying to execute ./cqlsh . But it is giving the below error:

```
Python Cassandra driver not installed, or not on PYTHONPATH.
You might try "pip install cassandra-driver".

Python: /usr/local/bin/python
Module load path: ['/home/ubuntu/Downloads/apache-cassandra-3.11.2-bin/apache-cassandra-3.11.2/bin/../lib/six-1.7.3-py2.py3-none-any.zip', '/home/ubuntu/Downloads/apache-cassandra-3.11.2-bin/apache-cassandra-3.11.2/bin/../lib/futures-2.1.6-py2.py3-none-any.zip', '/home/ubuntu/Downloads/apache-cassandra-3.11.2-bin/apache-cassandra-3.11.2/bin/../lib/cassandra-driver-internal-only-3.11.0-bb96859b.zip/cassandra-driver-3.11.0-bb96859b', '/home/ubuntu/Downloads/apache-cassandra-3.11.2-bin/apache-cassandra-3.11.2/bin', '/usr/local/lib/python27.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages']

Error: can't decompress data; zlib not available
```

I have already python, zlib, cassandra-driver all installed but the above error is still coming.

Comment: Could you provide all the steps you did including full install commands that led you here?

Comment: yeah, I downloaded the cassandra from the official site
and run ./cassandra
and run ./cqlsh

Comment: apart from it due to this error, I went installing python 2.7.6 , cython , pip, pip3, zlib,  zlib1g-dev but still couldn't fix the issue

Answer (score -1):

Provided you downloaded the tarball version of Cassandra and unpacked it correctly, the only thing I can assume is that you have a corrupted/incomplete copy.

Earlier this year, I revised the Cassandra installation instructions on the Apache website ([CASSANDRA-15466](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-15466)).

If you follow the installation instructions on a clean Ubuntu 18.04 or 20.04 server verbatim, it will work first time, every time -- https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/getting_started/installing.html#installing-the-binary-tarball. Cheers!

Comment: Hi, I tried installing with the link provided through debian. It got installed but on running cqlsh, it gives : `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/cqlsh.py", line 146, in <module>
    import six
zipimport.ZipImportError: can't decompress data; zlib not available`

Comment: It sounds like there's something wrong with your Python installation, possibly not using Python 2.7. Run `python -V` and if it doesn't report 2.7, you need to figure out what's wrong with your Python.